# How I can make Greenshot pattern start from 1 to 9999999?

Tags: regex, capture, snipping, greenshot

I recently started using [Greenshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenshot) and it's a fantastic program for screen capture, but I have problem with `${NUM}` pattern. It starts like this:

```
000001,000002,etc.,...
```

How I can make it start like this?

```
1,2,3...10,11...99,100,etc.,...
```

Also how I can reset it to start again from zero?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the ${NUM} pattern is giving 6 digits, but it does appear to be intentional. When I tested (version 1.3.272) it was consistently 6 digits regardless of whether I used just `${NUM}` or `something${NUM}`. You could suggest this as an improvement [on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/issues).

As for resetting the variable, that is done in settings. From the editor, go to Edit > Preferences > Expert and change "The number for the $NUM in the filename" to 0 (or whatever value you want). This might also make a good feature request, having the counter reset itself when you move to a new directory. [Expert settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfYwV.png)

Answer (score 0):

My Output Filename pattern is `screen${NUM}` and this doesn't happen to me.
The numbers started long ago as single-digit.

The help description is : "${NUM} incrementing number, 6 digits".

I think that Greenshot insists not on 6 digits, but that the total filename
have at least 6 characters.

You can work around it with my pattern.
Otherwise, you should contact the developer of Greenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good answer from FancyFranks regarding the resetting of the Number values and pointing us to Github.

Lakritzator describes the implemented solution for the requested feature here on the 8th Feb 2022:

**Being able to choose the number of digits for ${NUM} Filename pattern
#376**
https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/issues/376#issuecomment-1032812128

`screenshots.${NUM:p3,0}.png` or even simpler `screenshots.${NUM:p3}.png` will create a number using the current value of the variable `NUM` padded `p` with three characters `3` being a literal zero `0`. This will result in `screenshot.321.png` if you have set the NUM to 320 on the expert preferences settings tab.

If you do not want padding at all, this should have been possible using an empty padding for the default six digit numbers `1`..`999999`: `${NUM:p6,}`, though this seems not to work for me. Instead it drops the `NUM` value completely. That is `screenshots.${NUM:p6,}.png` results in `screenshots..png` instead of `screenshots.21.png` in case you have `NUM` set to e.g. a two-digit number `20`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question myself and through trial and error, I got it! Hopefully, it will help someone else along the way.

`${NUM:p3,0}` will pad the end of the number, so you will get 100, 200, 300, and so on. `${NUM:p-3,0}` will pad with leading zeros, so you get 001, 002, 003, etc.

Remember to set the `${NUM}` to "0" in the expert preferences settings tab when you start a new capture sequence.