# Set NUM variable

Tags: capture, greenshot

How to set NUM variable to required one in Greenshot software? I was expecting to enter it instead of word "pattern", but I can't change it.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1729678/how-i-can-make-greenshot-pattern-start-from-1-to-9999999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next number for NUM to use is found in the file
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Greenshot\Greenshot.ini`.

You will find in it these lines :

```
; The number for the ${NUM} in the filename pattern, is increased automatically after each save.
OutputFileIncrementingNumber=???
```

You may set `OutputFileIncrementingNumber` to whatever value you like.
The starting value is `1`.